# Rotate a 3D Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d, rotation

Hi dear Matlab users,

I would like to rotate a x,y,z matrix, representating a 3D image, in order to maximum project it perpendicularly to a plane define by 3 known x,y,z points inside the matrix volume.

This matrix is imported from an ImageJ stack in which the x,y resolution is set at 0.283µm/pixel and the z spacing between images is 3.19µm. So i will need to do some interpolation.

It seems that there is already many posts on this topic online but, at this point, i need a more general advice to choose the best method to address this problem.

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Benoit

Comment: What field are you on? Can be this programming problem translated to a scientific problem? I ask because this totally sounds like tomography

Comment: If that is not the case, when you say maximum project it, what do you mean? Interpolate it? get the maximum value that a perpendicular line to the plane can get over its path? Can you explain in more detail your problem?

Comment: Do you have the image processing toolbox?

Comment: and you have seen [this submission](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21080-resampling-volume-or-image-with-affine-matrix) on the File Exchange?

Comment: Ander : the 3D image i'm talking about was aquired on a confocal microscope and so represent slices of a 3D object. When i speak about max projection i effectively mean the maximum value that a perpendicular line to the plane can get over its path. I need first to rotate the matrix (in a way that the plane define by my 3 points will be perpendicular to the new obsrevation angle) and then do the max projection.

Comment: Rody : I have the imaging processing tool box, and i'm currently looking at the link you gave me. Thx